# In CRM 2013 Plugin Getting dates with wrong time, however UI don't have time field. How to remove time from date

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm currently retrieving a date string from CRM via the following

```
Entity dateDeliveryRequiredImage = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["DeliveryRequired"];
```

Which does work however for some reason it seems to be retrieving a time when I am creating a CSV file via the following line

```
dateDeliveryRequiredImage["requestdeliverby"].ToString()
```

Any idea where it is getting the time from firstly as there's no where to input time (and its saying it's 11pm??)

And more importanly how to get rid of it

Thanks, Shaun

**Update**

After imputing required code following errors appeared

```
 if (!timeZoneCode.HasValue)
            return;
```

An object of type convertible to 'system.timeanddate' is required

```
var response = (LocalTimeFromUtcTimeResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(request);
```

_serviceProxy does not exist in the current context

My code for service is as follows;

```
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));


        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

However inputting service or context did nothing

Finally
     new QueryExpression(UserSettings.EntityLogicalName)

With user settings not existing in current context

**Update Of Code Now Working**

```
private DateTime RetrieveLocalTimeFromUTCTime(DateTime utcTime, IOrganizationService service)
    {

        int? timeZoneCode = RetrieveCurrentUsersSettings(service);


        if (!timeZoneCode.HasValue)
            throw new Exception("Can't find time zone code");



        var request = new LocalTimeFromUtcTimeRequest
        {
            TimeZoneCode = timeZoneCode.Value,
            UtcTime = utcTime.ToUniversalTime()
        };

        var response = (LocalTimeFromUtcTimeResponse)service.Execute(request);

        return response.LocalTime;
        //var utcTime = utcTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        //var localDateOnly = response.LocalTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }

    private int? RetrieveCurrentUsersSettings(IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var currentUserSettings = service.RetrieveMultiple(
        new QueryExpression("usersettings")
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("localeid", "timezonecode"),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions =
        {
            new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.EqualUserId)
        }
            }
        }).Entities[0].ToEntity<Entity>();

        return (int?)currentUserSettings.Attributes["timezonecode"];
    }
```

Please note difference from code below is the following lines;

```
}).Entities[0].ToEntity<Entity>();

return (int?)currentUserSettings.Attributes["timezonecode"];
```

Comment: Can understand what is the issue, Can you please explain it in detail. Also it will be helpful if you can share plugin code.

Comment: When I'm inputting the postentityimage into a string ready to be outputted to a CSV file I'm getting a date and time back, however all I need is the date. My plugin code is quite large and didn't feel that it was neccisery to post it all in there, only the required code that is above, however I can change it for you if you like?

Comment: Ok I understand the problem. Is giving you the default time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRM is putting the default time which you can remove before writing to CSV as following:

```
DateTime dateAndTime = (DateTime)dateDeliveryRequiredImage["requestdeliverby"];
var date = dateAndTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

In case you want to write the default time to CSV. you can use as following:

```
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

Dynamics CRM 2011 stores all DateTime fields in UTC time, so by using the ‘DateTime.UtcNow’ approach our dates will be converted into UTC time before hitting the database. For example,  default time is 12:00:00, in database it will be stored as 11:00:00. That is why you are getting 11PM in your plugin. When our users read the date through CRM it will be converted back into their local time zone and user will read correctly time.

**UPDATE**

```
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
        serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));


IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

// This retrieves the UTC time
DateTime dateAndTime = (DateTime)dateDeliveryRequiredImage["requestdeliverby"];

// This converts the UTC time to your local time
var localDate = RetrieveLocalTimeFromUTCTime(dateAndTime, service);

// It will give you the correct date
var date = dateAndTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

To Convert the UTC to local time. Please check the code below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrive the local time from the UTC time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="utcTime"></param>
    /// <param name="service"></param>
    private DateTime RetrieveLocalTimeFromUTCTime(DateTime utcTime, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        int? timeZoneCode = RetrieveCurrentUsersSettings(service);

        if (!timeZoneCode.HasValue)
            throw new Exception("Can't find time zone code");

        var request = new LocalTimeFromUtcTimeRequest
        {
            TimeZoneCode = timeZoneCode.Value,
            UtcTime = utcTime.ToUniversalTime()
        };

        var response = (LocalTimeFromUtcTimeResponse)service.Execute(request);

        return response.LocalTime;
        //var utcTime = utcTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        //var localDateOnly = response.LocalTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the current users timezone code and locale id
    /// </summary>
    private int? RetrieveCurrentUsersSettings(IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var currentUserSettings = service.RetrieveMultiple(
        new QueryExpression("usersettings")
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("localeid", "timezonecode"),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions =
        {
            new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.EqualUserId)
        }
            }
        }).Entities[0].ToEntity<UserSettings>();

        return currentUserSettings.TimeZoneCode;
    }
```

Ref: [Sample: Retrieve time zone information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh547406.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, your code has removed the time, but quite bizarly it's taking the date one day behind from what I've selected, any suggestions @Scorpion

Comment: Before removing the date part, Convert the UTC time to Local Time. It will sort out the problem.

Comment: Please check my updated code. Your default time is 12 Min night, when system converting it to UTC, its taking time one hour behind (11 PM of previous day). Which cause the date difference. In updated code, I am converting the UTC time to your local time and than removing the time part. Now you will get the correct date.

Comment: Hi @Scorpion, I tired the following with no luck

 `DateTime dateAndTime = (DateTime)dateDeliveryRequiredImage["requestdeliveryby"];
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(dateAndTime);
var date = dateAndTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Comment: Looking at the code you posted now, can't find where in the code to put it exactly without it messing everything else up

Comment: Okay, few errors have appeared will post an update on original post, Thanks @Scorpion

Comment: Errors just been posted, sorry, had to attend a meeting

Comment: Do you have any C# developer in your team?

Comment: errors are very simple. replace `_serviceproxy` with `service` in your code.

Comment: I've tried and no change, still says it doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: make sure you have added these references. `using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;` `using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;` `using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;` I will update the code to make it more simple for you. But to be honest I have give you an idea. Its up to you to get it working. errors are not with code. I can ensure you code is right. Make sure you have added required references and you are passing right parameters.

Comment: Their also already in my code, appreciate your comments and time given to help

Comment: Please check the updated code. Hopefully it will sort out all your problems.